# Ember.js segmentation fault - node-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, segmentation-fault, node-sass

I recently moved some of my older projects to the new MacOS Catalina. I have an [Ember.js](https://emberjs.com/) project that is giving me a segmentation fault when trying to run the app. I found this [github](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-cli-materialize/issues/319) that seems like they’re experiencing something similar and they claim the cause of this issue is the npm module node-sass. I’ve tried rebuilding node-sass, I’ve tried removing node_modules completely and re-installing, nothing works. I’ve found this module ‘segfault-handler’ which prints out a stack trace that’s suppose to help me debug this issue but I’m not sure how to interpret the output. Here’s what that output looks like, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
PID 11228 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x0
0   segfault-handler.node               0x0000000101f9b0c0 _ZL16segfault_handleriP9__siginfoPv + 304
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff715a75fd _sigtramp + 29
2   ???                                 0x0000000102b97d30 0x0 + 4340677936
3   binding.node                        0x000000010a0dca0a _ZN4Sass4Util11isPrintableEPNS_7RulesetE17Sass_Output_Style + 192
4   binding.node                        0x000000010a09ff07 _ZN4Sass6OutputclEPNS_7RulesetE + 73
5   binding.node                        0x000000010a090383 _ZN4Sass7InspectclEPNS_5BlockE + 149
6   binding.node                        0x000000010a0357d6 _ZN4Sass7Context6renderEPNS_5BlockE + 50
7   binding.node                        0x000000010a0d2a7d sass_compiler_execute + 107
8   binding.node                        0x000000010a0d2697 _Z20sass_compile_contextP12Sass_ContextPN4Sass7ContextE + 34
9   node                                0x0000000100a17768 worker + 90
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff715b3109 _pthread_start + 148
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff715aeb8b thread_start + 15
zsh: segmentation fault  sudo ember s


ember-cli: 2.10.0
node: 6.17.1
os: darwin x64
```

Comment: can you share your `package.json`?

Answer (score 2):

First thing I noticed is that the version of node is old enough to potentially be causing you some problems.

> node: 6.17.1

Accordingly with [Node.js release](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#readme) you should use at least v10.x (but better v12.x or v14.x) if we take a look to [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) it seems v6.x is no loger suported neither by node-sass itself.

Once updated your Node.js version you could also update `npm` and `node-gyp` with following command executed as root:

```
# npm install -g npm node-gyp
```

Last remove your `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` once again, paying attention to any deprecation warning it emits and, if required, upgrade the deprecated packages; this could require to change your code, I sadly know it.

Hope this helps.